# Upgrade Lenovo G510 from Windows 10 32-bit to 64-bit?

Tags: windows-10, installation-media

I have a Lenovo G510 laptop that came without OS. I've installed on it Windows 7 32-bit.

This summer, I got my the upgrade to Windows 10. The 'About computer' section in the settings, it said that I have a 32 bit OS, but x64 based processor.

I've checked online and I saw that I can create a Windows 10 64-bit installation media, and install it on my computer and keep my files.

Can I really upgrade this computer to x64 OS? Will it make my laptop to run faster?

Thanks.

Comment: First determine if you have a 64-bit CPU.  If you do then you can install a 64-bit version of Windows.  There is absolutely no upgrade path from 32-bit version of Windows to a 64-bit version of Windows.

Comment: Almost all x86 CPUs about a decade back are 64 bits

Answer (score 1):

In short - yes you can upgrade it - all the processor variants on the g510 are 64bit.

The main problem is that although you have a 64bit processor, you've installed 32 bit Windows 7 and the windows 10 upgrade will only let you upgrade to 32bit windows 10.

If you are happy to do a clean install and you can back up all you important data then you can install 64bit Windows 10 - but don't forget - **THIS WILL WIPE YOUR DISK!**

If you have 3GB of memory or less, don't bother trying to upgrade to the 64 bit version as it generally needs a decent amount of memory to be happy.

Microsoft say 32bit win10 needs a minimum of 1GB and 64bit needs 2GB - These are bare minimums - they'll run, but will likely be subject to slowdowns if the OS uses the pagefile much I would probably have a minimum of  4GB and prefer 8GB for 64bit win10.

While digging around to make sure of my facts, I came across a guide if you really want to go for it.

The first sections about cpu and hardware shouldnt be a problem as it's a fairly recent laptop.

Anyway, here's the guide

http://www.howtogeek.com/228042/how-to-switch-from-32-bit-windows-10-to-64-bit-windows-10/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install Windows 10 x64, but if you do that you need to completely reinstall the system: you can upgrade from a Windows version to another without losing your files, but if you want to go from an architecture to another, then it's **completely necessary** to reinstall the O.S. with the architecture you want. If the change from an architecture to another could be possible, the system could get harmed because important 64-bit system files are being mixed with 32-bit files, and that could make a lot of problems.

You can create an USB installation media with the tool and install the O.S. from the booteable USB, but remember to **backup your files** .

Answer (score -2):

When you buy a Lenovo G510, it comes with Windows 8.1 (64-bit) operating system installed. It has an intel i5 processor and 64-bit compatibility tests pass on your laptop. You will need to download Windows 10 64-bit ISO image from Microsoft and burn the image to DVD or USB. I would suggest using NirSoft ProduKey to extract your existing Windows 10 license key. After you have this, then upgrade in place by loading DVD or USB.

Comment: [www.notebookcheck.net/Lenovo-G510-Notebook-Review.117221.0.html]